# Permissions are granted by default

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-5.0-lollipop, runtime-permissions

I'm not sure i fully understand this. So, for the <= 21 API version we can just use `AndroidManifest.xml` to request permissions, but Lollipop and higher APIs we have [Requesting permission on runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) feature. So i'm using it with this simpe code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    mPermissionsToBeAsked.clear();
    for (String permission : AudioRecordingThread.PERMISSIONS_NEEDED) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mPermissionsToBeAsked.add(permission);
        }
    } ....
```

Then, if that list is not empty i'm requesting them :

```
if (mPermissionsToBeAsked.size() > 0) {
   requestPermissions(mPermissionsToBeAsked.toArray(new String[0]), AUDIO_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

But, for some reason, on devices, for example, like Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 6.0.1, **all the permissions grandted by default when app is installed**. So i want to know why, BUT, it's there is an even bigger concerne, when i go to my application in Application Manager and **manually removing Microphone permision, in the app `checkSelfPermission(permission)` is still returning GRANTED**. So the questions:

1. Why on devices with API level Lollipop and higher all permissions are still granted by default and above code won't add anything into `mPersmissionToBeAsked`?
2. Why if i manually removing permission with title MICROPHONE in Application manager `checkSelfPermission(android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)` **still returns GRANTED**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Cross verify in your app gradle file the targetsdk version is greater than 22.

```
 defaultConfig {
        // -----
        targetSdkVersion 23
       //----
    }
```

If it is less than 23 than permission will automatically been granted to your app.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's Android M and above that handles permission granting. And that means you should have

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

or above. Otherwise the system considers that the developper did not target this version, meaning that the developper does not check for permissions.